# How to configure a route for an OpenShift app with nodeJS and express

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, openshift

I am new to OpenShift and I would like some help in order to configure the route for my app on OpenShift.

This is my port and ip configuration in the NodeJS - Express app that I'm trying to deploy:

```js
const server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT ||  process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server_ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || '0.0.0.0';

server.listen(server_port, server_ip, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${server_port}`);
});
```

With exactly the same configuration the application runs successfully in `localhost:5000` in Heroku. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I changed my project's port and ip as shown above and this is my YAML for the route:

```
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: *****-gitlab-io-be
  namespace: *****gitlabiobe
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/route.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/*****gitlabiobe/routes/*****-gitlab-io-be
  uid: 34fef86d-4051-11ea-bd30-0a580a810070
  resourceVersion: '155488429'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-01-26T15:33:31Z'
  labels:
    app: *****-gitlab-io-be
    app.kubernetes.io/component: *****-gitlab-io-be
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: *****-gitlab-io-be
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nodejs
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: *****-gitlab-io-be
    app.openshift.io/runtime: nodejs
    app.openshift.io/runtime-version: latest
  annotations:
    app.openshift.io/vcs-ref: master
    app.openshift.io/vcs-uri: 'https://gitlab.com/*****/*****.gitlab.io.be.git'
    openshift.io/host.generated: 'true'
spec:
  host: >-
    ************gitlabiobe.apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com
  subdomain: ''
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: *****-gitlab-io-be
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 5000-tcp
  wildcardPolicy: None
status:
  ingress:
    - host: >-
        *****gitlabiobe.apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com
      routerName: default
      conditions:
        - type: Admitted
          status: 'True'
          lastTransitionTime: '2020-01-26T15:33:31Z'
      wildcardPolicy: None
      routerCanonicalHostname: apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things to check:

1. The pod should be available (all containers are ready, all probes are passed etc)
2. NodeJS server have to listen to 0.0.0.0 address (not localhost)
3. OpenShift Service should forward 8080 port and it's selector identifies required pod, e.g.:

   ```
   kind: Service
   ...
   spec:
     selector:
       app: xxx
     ports:
       - name: 8080-tcp
         port: 8080
         protocol: TCP
         targetPort: 8080
   ```
4. The Route have to be mapped to required OpenShift Service and the its target port, e.g.:

   ```
   kind: Route
   ...
   spec:
     port:
       targetPort: 8080-tcp
     to:
       kind: Service
       name: xxx
       ...
   ```

Then you can use the route's host to reach the pod.

Comment: I updated the question with some changes in the app and the route that I made, I still don't have any result.

Comment: In the YAML of the route "targetPort: 5000-tcp" but "app is running on port 8080". Please check Pod, Service, Route according to port numbers

Comment: **NOTE** I'm marking this answer as right, and I would like to clarify for those who will run into the same issue that there are two different YAML in OpenShift, one is under the Service panel and one is under the Route panel, as shown in the answer.