# Can't deploy docker image on openshift

Tags: docker, openshift

I try to deploy my docker image from docker hub on openshift using both Openshift web console or minishift, all the processes seemed to be successful including Deployment, Service and Route. However when i click on the link to test my service it shows the error. I have tested my docker image and it work perfectly fine. [Openshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP0wk.png)
[Openshift Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5rcI.png)
[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsHXM.png)

Comment: Seeing as this is OpenShift Online, I would recommend reaching out to the community support channel: https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html

Comment: Although if you don't want to do that, can you provide the output from `oc get service -o yaml`

Comment: Thank for the reply. Here is the output https://codeshare.io/214jl1

Comment: Is your container completly unprivilged? Can it handle an user id above 1k? Because, openshift is an enterprise k8s cluser. It's not allowed to do any priviliged tasks in a container outside a build pipeline. And OC is running every container with an random injected uid. Thats why most of hub.docker.com and helm stuff is not working on OC.

Comment: Check pods status and events first. If it's okay then check pod/service/route as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920939/how-to-configure-a-route-for-an-openshift-app-with-nodejs-and-express/59922413#59922413

Comment: I have checked the pod status and everything is running. Here is my route and service https://codeshare.io/5RMKkB

Comment: AH I have fixed the issue now. Thank you all for the help.